# Привязка к каптче

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно сделать так, чтобы до введения каптчи кнопка "зарегистрироваться" была не активна, а после ввода становилась активной?

Comment: Какая версия капчи?  Ну или добавьте код, которым эта капча вызывается

Comment: Самодельная каптча

Comment: Меняйте  свойство `disabled` у кнопки.